# How to integrate Own Database in WSO2

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 IS 6.0.0 and it is working. I have even configured Service Providers which are working fine.

Now I have my own MYSQL Database which has its own table(local_users) with users in it. There are around 10 users.

I want those users to be able to log in to WSO2 MYAcount using a username and password from the "local_users" Table and not WSO2 User Store.

I have read the documentation [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/configure-a-jdbc-user-store/) which seems to only create WSO2 tables in MYSQL Database. But it doesn't take my table(local_users) from the same Database. I didn't find any option to give my table name or column name.

So my question is, is it possible to incorporate your own MYSQL DB Table with WSO2 Identity Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can plug your own database which has user data as a userstore to WSO2 IS.
For that, you have to write a custom userstore manager to manage the user store, because the DB schema is different than the schema used in WSO2 default userstores.

Refer to https://nishothan-17.medium.com/custom-user-store-manager-for-wso2-identity-server-5-11-0-6e23a4ddf1bb this guide for more information on writing a custom userstore manager and plug your own userstore to WSO2 IS.

Comment: Thank you Anuradha for your answer. Can you tell me how WSO2 saves passwords in the Database? What encryption or Hash it uses?

Comment: By default `SHA-256` is used as the hashing algorithm when storing passwords in userstores. However, you can use PBKDF2 if you use a JDBC userstore manager https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/secure-userstore-using-pbkdf2/